# Ansible module: EC2 add security group to running instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to add a 1 extra security group to a running instance. 
Reading the documentation you should be able to when you use this:

```
- name: "Attach SG"
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_ids:
      - "{{ ec2_instances.instances.0.instance_id }}"
    state: running
    group_id:
      - group1
      - group2
```

Now this does not work in our case so I am fetching all security groups and add the new one to the machine like this:

```
- name: "Attach SG"
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_ids:
      - "{{ ec2_instances.instances.0.instance_id }}"
    state: running
    group_id:
      - "{{ item.group_id }}"
  when: total_group_list.stdout == "nok"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ec2_instances.instances.0.network_interfaces.0.groups }}"
    - "{{ ic_sg_icinga_db }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.group_id }}"
```

The only problem is that now it runs this code for each group in those items so if `item1` has 3 groups and `item2` 1 it would `add` and `delete` all groups one by one leaving me with the last group only that it used:

```
TASK [c-icinga2-agent : Attach SG] 
changed: [bamboo] => (item=sg-1)
changed: [bamboo] => (item=sg-2)
changed: [bamboo] => (item=sg-3)
changed: [bamboo] => (item=sg-4)
```

result: 
host has only got `sg-4` and missing `sg-[1:3]`

Any one a idea on how to Append 1 security group with a ansible module and leaving the old security groups that are already on the host in tact?

The current tasks i have are:

1. Get all current security groups with: `ec2_instance_info` of 1 instance
2. Filtering of the current attached groups and check if the new one is already added
3. Attach SG if the new security group is not added.

The desired result would be that the `Attach SG` only runs once with all groups from `with_items` but I ran out of ideas / places to look on how to get this done.
help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [ec2_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_module.html#ec2-instance-module) module to manage the existing instance.

Comment: Yes I tried that, instead of changed it says OK now but still no new security group, just the old 3 the 4th one still not attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> result: host has only got sg-4 and missing sg-[1:3]

Well, yeah, because you *looped over* them, and say "the list of groups is **only** {{ item }}", when what you wanted is the [`union` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters)

```yaml
  group_id: "{{ 
       ec2_instances.instances.0.network_interfaces.0.groups
       | union([ic_sg_icinga_db]) }}"
  when: total_group_list.stdout == "nok"
```

It's probably possible to use `+` or `.extend()` on the `list`, too, but those two don't take uniqueness into consideration, whereas union does, by definition

Comment: Ah thanks I will play with that it looks like that will be my golden ticket after i filter a bit better !

Comment: Results in: `Invalid id: "['sg-1', 'sg-2', 'sg-3', 'sg-4']" (expecting "sg-` Altough a gian step forward its not adding the security groups and with `ec2_instance` it just says ok and does nothing

Comment: after some head scratches it all makes sense now :)